# Uncaught Error: Dropzone already attached reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, uikit, react-dropzone

I am using Creative Tim's [material dashboard pro kit](https://www.creative-tim.com/learning-lab/react/quick-start/material-dashboard/). In my React project.

I need to create a dropzone to upload CSV files.

This UI kit already provides a ready-to-use component for dropzone named `MDDropzone`.

But I am facing one issue: whenever I reload the page, I get an `Uncaught Error: Dropzone already attached` error on the console and the page went blank.

`MDDropzone.js` file -

```
function MDDropzone({ options }) {
  const [controller] = useMaterialUIController();
  const { darkMode } = controller;

  const dropzoneRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

    function createDropzone() {
      return new Dropzone(dropzoneRef.current, { ...options });
    }

    function removeDropzone() {
      if (Dropzone.instances.length > 0) Dropzone.instances.forEach((dz) => dz.destroy());
    }

    createDropzone();

    return () => removeDropzone();
  }, [options]);

  return (
    <MDDropzoneRoot
      component="form"
      action="/file-upload"
      ref={dropzoneRef}
      className="form-control dropzone"
      ownerState={{ darkMode }}
    >
      <MDBox className="fallback" bgColor="transparent">
        <MDBox component="input" name="file" type="file" multiple />
      </MDBox>
    <requiredeRoot>
  );
}

// Typechecking props for the MDDropzone
MDDropzone.propTypes = {
  options: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any).isRequired,
};

export default MDDropzone;
```

File where I am using this component -

```
function Test() {
  return (
    <div>
      Testing Dropzone
      <MDDropzone options={{ addRemoveLinks: true }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I believe I am missing something. Anyone can please help me out